# i am trying to get total amount from this query

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, mysql-5.6

```
SELECT ( ( `salary_log`.`emp_id`
          ,`salary_log`.`basic`+`salary_log`.`da`+`salary_log`.`allowance`)
        -( (`salary_log`.`deduction`-`provident_fund_info`.`pf_own_value`)
          +`salary_log`.`adjustment`+`salary_log`.`fine`
          +`salary_log`.`tax`+`provident_fund_info`.`pf_own_value`
         )
       )
FROM `salary_log`
       INNER JOIN `provident_fund_info`
          ON `provident_fund_info`.`emp_id`=`salary_log`.`emp_id` 
WHERE `salary_log`.`generate_date`='2017-12-01'
  AND `salary_log`.`statement_type`='salary';
```

> 1 queries executed, 0 success, 1 errors, 0 warnings
>
> Query:
>
> ```
> SELECT ( ( `salary_log`.`emp_id`
>           ,`salary_log`.`basic`+`salary_log`.`da`+`salary_log`.`allowance`)
>         -( (`salary_log`.`deduction`-`pro...
> ```
>
> Error Code: 1241
>
> Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Comment: ,Syntax error, remove the ( ) from select statement

Comment: You've incorrectly placed `salary_log`.`emp_id` with your summation and subtraction operations...since employee id should not be part of salary calculations and you want employee id in different column than calculated salary, modify your query as suggested by @'Edgar Allan Bayron' in answer

Comment: Suggest `INDEX(statement_type, generate_date)`

Answer (score 2):

Error occurred due to a column which is not part of the equation is inside the parenthesis.

Try this:

```
SELECT
    s.emp_id, 
      (s.[basic] + s.da + s.allowance) -
        ((s.deduction - p.pf_own_value) +
          s.adjustment + s.fine + s.tax +
           p.pf_own_value) AS solution
FROM salary_log s
INNER JOIN provident_fund_info p ON p.emp_id = s.emp_id
WHERE s.generate_date = '2017-12-01'
    AND s.statement_type = 'salary';
```